# Generate css with sass using in realtime

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass

I have a web application with the back-end in node.js and front-end in react.js.
I have written the css using sass and am wondering if I am can somehow connect node and sass so that on request from the user (example font-size change) at the client-side a new css file can be generated and sent to the web application.
If this is possible that what module/library do i need to take a look at?

Comment: Sass isn't capable of that. If you're looking to be able to deploy your code after making a change you can use Capistrano but you have to be comfortable with working within the terminal http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

Answer (score 0):

SCSS is a CSS precompiler. It's only use is to generate CSS when compiled. Write a simple syntax are generate the CSS for the browser to use it. Any use of SCSS other than this is not what it is made for.

Now coming to your use case, all you need is themeable CSS. If you need just the change in font-size or theme color, you don't even need an extra css. Explore CSS4 variables. Here is a very basic use of CSS4 for theming. https://dev.to/idoshamun/theming-with-css-variables-322f